# Object equivalent to GridCellNgh?

Tags: java, agent-based-modeling, repast-simphony

I am using Repast Simphony to build a simulation using java in Eclipse. The simulation has an agent class that functions within a "geography" context.

There are other contexts that agents can move within including "grid" and "space". These are 2D projections where a "geography" context is a GIS projection.

The "grid" package comes with a set of objects/methods as does the "geography" package. One of those in the grid package is called GridcellNgh which creates a Moore neighborhood or a "filter" around a particular grid point. Does anyone know of an object that can perform a similar function to the GridCellNgh that will work in the Geography package projection?

http://repast.sourceforge.net/docs/api/repast_simphony/repast/simphony/space/gis/Geography.html

http://repast.sourceforge.net/docs/api/repast_simphony/repast/simphony/query/space/grid/GridCellNgh.html

Or perhaps is it possible to build both a Grid and a Geography in the context? (I think this is less likely as Geography is a GIS projection and Grid is a 2D projection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Geography package, use the method .getObjectsWithin()

Parameters: the bounding envelope

Create an envelope object of various dimensions (2D plane)

http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Envelope.html